# Wiring for Ceiling Fan and Light

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I removed an old ceiling light/fan fitting. There were 4 wires coming out of the attic into this old unit: copper, red, black, white.

I have a new light/fan combo to fit. It only has 3 wires: green, white, black.

How do I join these?

Then for the wall switch:

There used to be 2 switches; one for the fan, one for the light.

The new wall switch is a single unit with a light button and a fan button on the front. There are 3 wires coming out the back; green, black and white.

How do I wire the wall fittings?

Many thanks if you can help.

Comment: Did either of the devices come with documentation that includes wiring diagrams?

Comment: or a diagram on the new switch

Comment: Or even brand and model number/name of fan.  Also did the switch come with the fan?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the new switch came with the new light/fan unit.  In that case, cap the red wire in both boxes.  It must be a communicating switch.  So wire it as you would any single-pole light switch and light.